# How do you choose what naming convention to use for namespaces and class in c#?

Tags: c#, class, namespaces, naming-conventions

When declaring namespaces and classes I noticed there are at least two ways of doing so. Two most common cases I came across are:

```
namespace Vehicles
{
    public class Car
    {
         public string Make {get; set;}
         public int Year {get; set;}
         public string Model  {get; set;}
    }
}

namespace Vehicles.Car.Engine
{
    public class Engine
    {
         public string Type {get; set;}
         public int Cylinder {get; set;}    
    }
}

namespace Vehicles
{
    public class Car
    {
         public string Make {get; set;}
         public int Year {get; set;}
         public string Model  {get; set;}
    }

    public class CarEngine
    {
         public string Type {get; set;}
         public int Cylinder {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Regarding naming conventions, how do you choose a naming convention for namespaces/classes, and how do you call this convention when you combine class names into one long class name?

Comment: When you deconfuse yourself with regard to whatever it is you are trying to classify, you'll have a better clue. Think about it. Car.Car, Car.Engine.Engine, Car.CarEngine. Consider Vehicles.Car.Engine.

Comment: Just an example, i will update my question

Answer (score 1):

Your namespaces should be logical domains, your class names should be by what they do specifically, while still considering what problem you are trying to solve.

For example

```
namespace Vehicles.Cars
{
    public class CarBase
    {
         public string Make {get; set;}
         public int Year {get; set;}
         public string Model  {get; set;}
    }

    public class Toyota : CarBase
    {
    }
}
namespace Vehicles.Cars.Engines
{
    public class DeiselEngine
    {
         public string Type {get; set;}
         public int Cylinder {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in this case it depends if you will have Engines of other things.

If this is the only example of Engine in your system, just call it `Engine`.

Otherwise, I would go for `CarEngine` as it would be easier to identify the class you're trying to find.

Also, think the namespaces as a way to organize your classes in the same way you organize your files into folders. It always helps.

Think about `control+ting` and searching for `Engine` when you have many different classes with the same name.

There is no right or wrong here, just make sure that your team has its own set of rules visible to everyone, ensure the rules during pull-requests and you gonna be fine.

And don't worry too much about it, naming and cache invalidation are the most difficult problems in computer science.

Comment: Is there a same logic when creating dto classes? i noticed that visual studio is actually using long class names when you paste xml as object

Comment: I usually create them with the main original class name just adding the Dto suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Depends more on how you want to structure your application. Not every app needs a the same granularity and type of structure. Main criteria is that it has to be simple and maintain logic with the problems/scenarios your application is solving. Also, not everything is inside some other thing, your engine goes inside a car but an engine by itself is very complex and it's own thing:

```
namespace Vehicles
{

public class MotorBike
{
 Engine Engine { get; set; }
 List<Tire> Tires {get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
 Engine Engine { get; set; }
 List<Tire> Tires {get; set; }
}

public class CompactCar : Car
{
}

public class Engine
{
 List<Pistons> { get; set;}
 ...
}

public class DieselEngine : Engine 
{
 ...
}

public class Tire
{
 int Diameter {get; set;}
 ...
}

}
```